# Can C# decision get better in my View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible to improve my code and make it more simpler.
Iam in code trying to right and left-align the image with margin.

```
if(alig =="left")
{
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">Heeeeej</div> 
   <div style="float:left">AAAan</div>  ------> !align =left margin-right:10px;

}
else
{
   <div style="float:right; ">Heeeeej</div>
   <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">Aaaaaan</div>
}
```

Comment: If align is left.. both div must float left

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the variable in the css style directly which would look like:

```
<div style="float:@(alig); margin-right:10px;">Heeeeej</div> 
   <div style="float:@(alig)">AAAan</div>
```

I am supposing that the `align` variable will have either **left** or **right** as value in it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use class names to distinguish styles (and pull inlined styles out of HTML tags):

```
<div @if(alig == "left") { <text>class="left-align"</text> }>
   <div class="first-div">Heeeeej</div> 
   <div class="second-div">AAAan</div>
</div>
```

And, in either a referenced CSS file or in an inline `<style>` tag:

```
.first-div
{
    float:right;
}
.second-div
{
    float:left; 
    margin-right:10px;
}
//this behavior will supercede the above behavior when .left-align is on an ancestor
.left-align .first-div
{
    float:left; 
    margin-right:10px;
}
.left-align .second-div
{
    float:left
    margin-right:auto;
}
```